# TopShelf Service Installation not working

Tags: c#, .net, windows, installation, topshelf

I've built this windows service which I ensured works locally. Now, although TopShelf's "ServiceName install" command's output indicates the install as successful, the service is nowhere to be found.

This is my service configuration code:

```
HostFactory.Run(servConfig => 
             {
                servConfig.Service<TimerService>(servInst => 
                {
                    servInst.ConstructUsing(
                        () => new TimerService());

                    servInst.WhenStarted(execute => execute.Start());
                    servInst.WhenStopped(execute => execute.Stop());
                });

                servConfig.SetServiceName("StayActiveService");
                servConfig.SetDisplayName("Stay active service");
                servConfig.SetDescription("Automatic timer setter");

                servConfig.StartAutomatically();
             });
```

Comment: What do you mean by _the service is nowhere to be found_? Is it not working or you can find it?

Comment: After installation I expect it to show up in Windows Services list & due to the configuration, start right away. None of that happens. It works when I run the (console) app explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add this line and try:

```
servConfig.RunAsLocalSystem();
```

Answer (score 0):

It magically fixed itself after some tries but there was definitely a permission warning windows event log having to do with "LocalSystem" so [your](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10943756/%C3%96nder-tipio%C4%9Flu) suggestion might help too.